# Place a button regardless of grid layout bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, grid-layout

I'm trying to create a sidebar with a floating arrow button that'll collapse the bar (a bit similar to, for example [this codepen code](https://codepen.io/boo0330/pen/gpQVKB)).

I'm using bootstrap4, and using `container-fluid` with a `row` that's divided by 2-8-2 (2 columns for left sidebar, 8 columns for main content and another 2 columns for right sidebar).

I'm not sure if I need to adjust the row and replace one of the columns to put the floating button in it, or I can somehow break out of the grid layout and put the button between columns 2 and 3 (let's say to be stretched between "columns" 1.5 and 2.5, or 2 and 2.5).

I wasn't able to find a floating button mechanism online that used bootstrap's grid layout, so I'm opening a new question.

For example, put a floating button in the red area in the following picture:

[image]

---

Edit:

To @Imran Rafiq Rather's request, here's the HTML code (as you can see, divided to 3 parts in a single row). I can simplify it if needed, all of the content inside it is of no importance to the question itself.

```
<!--main row (second row) in the grid layout-->
    <div class="container-fluid ml-n3">
        <div class="row" name="main-row">

            <!--sidebar-left-->
            <div class="col-2 position-fixed" style="height: 100vh;" name="sidebar-left">
                
                <ul  class="list-group bg-secondary h-100 collapse show" id="sb-left">
                    <li class="list-group-item bg-secondary border-0">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block text-white-50" role="button" name="explore">#Explore</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item bg-secondary border-0">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block text-white-50" role="button" name="bookmarks">Bookmarks</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item bg-secondary border-0">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block text-white-50" role="button" name="lists">Lists</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item bg-secondary border-0">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block text-white-50" role="button" name="moments">Moments</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item bg-secondary border-0">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block text-white-50" role="button" name="settings">Settings</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item bg-secondary border-0 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#post-tweet-id">Tweet</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item bg-secondary mt-5">
                        <div class="mt-5"></div>    
                        <div class="row d-flex">    
                            <div class="col-auto">
                                <img src="logo.png" class="rounded-circle img-fluid" style="height: 40px" alt="Profile Picture" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                            <div>user-name</div>
                            <div class="text-white"><small>@username</small></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <!--main-content-->
            <div class="col-8 offset-2 container-fluid" name="main-content">
                <div class="card mx-3 my-5"> <!--mb-5 mt-3-->
                    <div class="row no-gutters bg-dark text-white-50">
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <img src="profile.jpg" style="height:50px;" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="card-block px-2">
                                <div class="card-header"><a href="#" class="link text-decoration-none">@Username</a></div>
                                <div class="card-body" onclick="setInfo(this)" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tweet-id">Content</div>
                                <div class="card-footer">
                                    <span class="btn-toolbar btn-group-sm px-5">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn mx-auto text-white-50 rounded-circle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#post-comment"><i class="far fa-comment-alt"></i></button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn mx-auto text-white-50 rounded-circle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tweet-id"><span data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#comments"><i class="far fa-comments"></i></span></button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn mx-auto text-white-50 rounded-circle"><i class="fas fa-retweet"></i></button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn mx-auto text-white-50 rounded-circle"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn mx-auto text-white-50 rounded-circle"><i class="far fa-share-square"></i></button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>           
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--sidebar-right-->
            <div class="col-2 position-fixed offset-10 overflow-auto" style="height: 89vh;" name="sidebar-right">
                <ul class="list-group bg-secondary h-100" name="sb-right">
                    <button type="button" href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-secondary text-white-50 mx-auto">
                        <div><small>name-of-trend</small><div>
                        <div><h4>#Explore</h4></div>
                        <div><small>num-of-tweets</small></div>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-secondary text-white-50 mx-auto">
                        <div><small>name-of-trend</small><div>
                        <div><h4>#Explore</h4></div>
                        <div><small>num-of-tweets</small></div>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-secondary text-white-50 mx-auto">
                        <div><small>name-of-trend</small><div>
                        <div><h4>#Explore</h4></div>
                        <div><small>num-of-tweets</small></div>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-secondary text-white-50 mx-auto">
                        <div><small>name-of-trend</small><div>
                        <div><h4>#Explore</h4></div>
                        <div><small>num-of-tweets</small></div>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-secondary text-white-50 mx-auto">
                        <div><small>name-of-trend</small><div>
                        <div><h4>#Explore</h4></div>
                        <div><small>num-of-tweets</small></div>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-secondary text-white-50 mx-auto">
                        <div><small>name-of-trend</small><div>
                        <div><h4>#Explore</h4></div>
                        <div><small>num-of-tweets</small></div>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-secondary text-white-50 mx-auto">
                        <div><small>name-of-trend</small><div>
                        <div><h4>#Explore</h4></div>
                        <div><small>num-of-tweets</small></div>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-info text-white mx-auto">
                        <div><h6>Show more...</h6></div>
                    </button>
                    
                </ul>      
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Share your code here. I will do it for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `sidebar` create a button like `<button>X</button>`. Then use the following CSS.

```
.sidebar{
  position:relative;
}

button{
  position:absolute;
  top:45%;
  right:-1rem;
}
```

**Note:** `button` should be immediate child of `aside`. This way button comes out of the normal flow and we can place it anywhere within `aside`.

**As a general rule:**

> Whenever we have a parent with `position:relative`. We can use
> `position:absolute` on its child element and place it anywhere within
> the parent :) Out of the normal flow of execution !!!

Comment: Nice! I wonder why this works. I tried manipulating the position of the button but it always constrained me inside the column it was in. Is it because of the "position: absolute"?

Comment: @ Yechiam Weiss:  Yup

Comment: Whenever we have a parent with position:relative. We can use position:absolute on any of its children and place it anywhere within the parent :)

Comment: Some not so good people exist in the world... I really don't understand sometimes ... Why coders behave this way :) Anyways :) Hope your query is resolved ...

Comment: Yes, thank you. Now I'll need to play with it a little and learn how to move it to the left when I make the sidebar disappear :) Also, my sidebar is pos:fixed, and it still works. So I guess it doesn't necessarily require relative?

Comment: Ya, They work the same way. Let me guide you a bit. You will need to set a transform:translate() to close the sidebar smoothly., set a transition: all 0.5s ease; on sidear. And when the button is clicked it will move smoothly. You can try some animation keyframes as well. These are my hints. And yes change button content based on a variable in javascript !!! Best of luck to you.

Comment: And yes!!! You are most welcome :) If you stuck anywhere let me know... You may share your codepen.io link of your code. And I can debug stuff for you if you get stuck... But first you need to give it a good try :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed encouraging to receive such helpful help, and thank you for your advice on the transformation, I will use it (currently just "collapsing" it; bootstrap more limited than I thought it was) :)